# How can Enel reach the moon?

Tags: one-piece

On the mini-series in Manga, Enel goes to the moon. It's a side story titled [Enel's Great Space Operations](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Enel%27s_Great_Space_Operations). How can he reach the moon?

1. He goes to space where there is no air, how can he breathe?
2. It's a really long distance, the distance between earth and moon is 384,400 km (238,900 miles). And considering that *One Piece* takes place in the [sixteenth century](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/6843/when-does-one-piece-takes-place), the average speed of a ship at that time was less than 10 knot (18.52 kph/11.5 mph), it will take more than 2 years to reach the moon with a ship like that.
3. Can't he just use his power to reach the moon? (I don't know if lightning can go through space or not, maybe Kizaru can do it better?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem I see is that you are using the logic of our history versus logic of *One Piece*.

In the 16th century, they did not have ships that could travel in the air nor in space for that matter.

1. According to the [Wikia - Enel](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Enel),

   > His mini-series suggests he does not need to breathe and can survive outside of the atmosphere. However, his electricity-based powers have no effect on certain substances such as rubber, making Luffy a formidable enemy, as he is immune to Enel's powers.
2. You're using the logic of our history vs *One Piece*. The ship they used was the Ark Maxim which is a flying ship, stuff that we did not have in the 16th century. Also, Enel used his electricity powers to power the ship itself so it's possible to say that the ship could possibly reach very high speeds in space, there's nothing to slow down the ship. All they would need is a powerful thrust force to move in space, which can most likely be done using the chemical vats on the ship.

   As the [Wikia - Ark Maxim](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Ark_Maxim) states,

   > The Maxim is capable of flight, even in space. Enel's electrical energy is her main power supply, while two hundred Jet Dials are used as a backup power supply to keep the ark in the air for an hour if something were to happen to the Ark's mechanism. Enel used the gold from the Shandora ruins as a conductor for his electricity.

   The Wikia states this about the vats

   > Enel can use Maxim to create massive lightning storms via a combination of chemical vats that produce storms clouds and his own lightning abilities. One of these thunderbolts is enough to burn down an entire village, and Enel can create a giant thundercloud that can destroy an entire island.
3. I don't believe he can reach the moon just by his own power, wouldn't that imply that he could fly or teleport with his lightning powers. He does use his powers as previously stated only to fly the Ark Maxim to the moon though.

Comment: First, I'm using our history because I have no idea how fast that ship is. And from what I saw on anime, that ship is slow. So if I want to estimate its speed, I compared Maxim with our history ship's speed. And second, on manga he can suddenly standing beside Sanji and attacked him, so I assumed he can move at the speed of lightning, why can't he move toward moon it self? Maybe there is a limit power or something?

Comment: Shinobu that's because the example your giving is moving on land... That's like saying the because he's super fast, the Flash, can run to the moon... I don't ever remember seeing him being capable of flight.

Comment: Ok, I think lightning can't goes up and I never see him flying either, thanks for clearing that up

Comment: Oh another thing to mention is that Enel can perhaps create a large thrust force using the chemical vats on the ship.  Though it's only speculation.. the wikia states "Enel can use Maxim to create massive lightning storms via a combination of chemical vats that produce storms clouds and his own lightning abilities."

Comment: maybe you can add it on your answer, also it will be better if you can give us a link on a wiki from your answer, because I still can't find it on wiki you mentioned above

Comment: It's the one piece wikia

Answer (score 1):

We never see the ship running at its full speed as Enel was trying to get the golden bell or wanted the extra gold before leaving Skypiea. Therefore, we don't know its true speed, he also designed the ship showing a high level of intellect.

Answer (score 0):

The breath dials. They blow out air enough to keep it in the air on earth for a whole hour, that's a tremendous amount of force with which one can propel themselves in space where there are minimal drag forces, allowing for that force to make the ship go very very fast.

Considering how un-aerodynamic it is and how much metal is likely in it (almost an entire city of gold's worth), it would likely have around as much or more force than our spaceflights use to blast off into space. Also, considering that's a whole hour of constant use, it's quite possible it's more "fuel" that our spaceships have, thus allowing for the actual speed issue to be resolved.

As for the why he can't use lightning, lightning cannot travel through the vacuum of space due to a lack of any "medium" with which to flow through, like Enel does through the air, metal, or otherwise, since to varying degrees, they allow for a flow of electrons. However, it is difficult to expect electrons to flow through, what is to my knowledge, emptiness.

Assuming Enel isn't an exception in the no-air, no-food, etc. and that he intended to bring people with him, there must have either been a legitimate reason for not only him but also even him intending to bring Nami into space. Otherwise, it is just "plot armor" and they just don't want real-world logic to apply for some stuff.

Comment: as for how the 4 little android things got up there.... must be plot armor. fairly sure they only used little balloons, which would pop before reaching outer space, let alone have a way of getting to the moon any time soon.

Answer (score 0):

It has been theorized that the moon is within the planet's atmosphere. I believe I heard it from a YouTuber and don't know if it is plausible. It would have many problems with physics and such, but considering it is a manga and they got to the moon with balloons, it goes against logic either way.

Comment: I wanted to leave it as a comment but it said I couldn’t.

Comment: Most answers will be vague and without source. It is a topic surrounded by many theories and very little proof. Between Enel flying to the moon, to being able to breathe, to the existence of space pirates, Enels returning to the planet, the straw hats going to the moon, the skypians and the two other winged races coming from the moon, to being able to get there by balloon and probably more.

Comment: If there's no official answer, there's no problem with answers being a theory as long as it is backed up by some explanations and references. In fact, your "comment" can be considered a valid answer now ;)